# Need to save the excel file for every run with the current timestamp

Tags: java, json, excel, selenium, aspose

I am using the below code to convert the json file to excel using aspose. I am able to convert the json file but i need to save the converted file for every run with the current timestamp and i need to run it daily so that it should create a folder daily with the date.

```
public class converter1 {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {   
    LocalDateTime date = LocalDateTime.now();
    DateTimeFormatter dateformat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy HH-mm-ss");
    String formatedate =date.format(dateformat);
    Workbook workbook = new Workbook(".//Files//output.json");       
    workbook.save(".//output-"+formatedate+".xlsx");            
    System.out.println("json file converted successfully");
}
```

}

Comment: What is the question? How to save a file? How to run the code daily?

Comment: @albina need to run it daily and should save  according to the timestamp

Comment: @albina It should create a folder with the date and save all the excel files which  are generated on that day.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try:

e.g.

**Sample code:**

```java
LocalDateTime date = LocalDateTime.now();
java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter dateformat = java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy");
String formatedate = date.format(dateformat);

java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter datetimeformat = java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy HH-mm-ss");
String formatedatetime = date.format(datetimeformat);

Workbook workbook = new Workbook(".//Files//output.json");
File file = new File(".//" + formatedate);
if (!file.exists())
{
    file.mkdir();
}
workbook.save(file.getPath()+ "//output-"+formatedatetime+".xlsx");
System.out.println("json file converted successfully");
```

PS. I am working as Support developer/ Evangelist at Aspose.